# Need help in writing regex to capture DNS logs

Tags: regex, cisco, umbrella

Below are the DNS Sample logs where i need to write a regex to capture the Hostname "**Renju123**". The log format structure is little different on both samples.

The log samples are given below:

"2018-12-12 13:25:30","Renju, Jacob,M(renjutest)","Renju, Jacob, M (rtest),Renju123,Default Site,Test/firewall","10.221.5.136","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","Allowed","16 (A)","NOERROR","1XX.1X.1XX.1XX.Test.com.","Computer Security"

"2018-12-12 13:09:55","rtest","Renju123,Default Site,Renju Renju/Renju","10.250.33.85","XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","Allowed","12 (PTR)","NOERROR","1XX.1X.1XX.1XX.Test.com.","Software/Technology"

The regex which i used is only capturing the first log hostname

> (?P(?<=),).*?(?=,.?Default)) [link here](https://regex101.com/r/MRhKn5/2)

But i would like to have a single regex to capture HostNames (Renju123) from both the sample logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you might do (according to the comments) is match a double quote or a comma 1+ times using `[",]+` and then capture in a group matching 1+ word characters. Then `,Default` follows so that you could match again:

Your match will be in the `HostName` group.

```
[",]+(?P<HostName>\w+),Default
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZeCVRM/1)

If your hostname starts with a word character, you could use lookarounds and a word boundary `\b`

```
(?<=[,"])\b(?P<HostName>\w+)(?=,Default)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aZobf0/1)

Comment: @ The fourth bird   --Thanks for the regex. You regex worked like a charm. But i would like  a small tweak. Would it be possible to negate Renju Test/Firewall from  capturing. Below sample log is given.  Also the link-- https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/3                                      "2018-12-12 14:29:49","Default Site","Renju Test/Firewal,Default Site","10.250.33.8","1XX.1X.1XX.1XX.Test.com","Allowed","28 (AAAA)","NXDOMAIN","targets.",""

Comment: @List25 You could match 1+ wordcharacters instead `[",]+(\w+),Default` to not match the space and the forward slash [demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/4) If you want to allow more than `\w` you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and specify what you would allow to match.

Comment: @ The fourth bird can you help me in updating the regex on your second one. Please see the demo-- https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/6

Comment: @List25 You could also match 1+ word characters instead of the negated character class `(?<=[,"])\b(?P<HostName>\w+)(?=,Default)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/7) Shall I update my answer with these regexes?

Comment: @List25 I have updated my answer with the last 2 regexes.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Can we negate charater "/"  but would need to capture the hostname if its contains Renju-123 but should not capture  "Renju Test / Firewall "https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/8

Comment: @List25 like this? https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/9 You can add to the character class what you want to match.

Comment: @List25 You could use a negated character class but then you have to specify what you do not allow to match like https://regex101.com/r/vpB3RH/10